# what is the meaning of this---"could you have been dreaming"

Tags: meaning, sentence, sentence-meaning

what is the meaning of this sentence---``"

***could you have been dreaming?***

Comment: We need more context. It could mean a whole bunch of different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Could you have been dreaming?*" -- Seeing there are several potential scenarios, I will create one and go with it for an answer.
A person describes an event and the listener asks the question above.  **The meaning of the question could be that the person asking is skeptically exploring that the event is too unusual, unreasonable or even expected.**
For instance, the event description could be this one: "I saw my late grandfather walking through the hallway last night when I startled awake by a noise outside."  Then, the question is asked, "Could you have been dreaming?"

Answer (score 1):

Dreaming = imagining. So the question asks if you imagined something (depends on the context).

Comment: why "could" is used there in this sentences